# Ffmpeg command to add shorter audio to video with loop

Tags: ffmpeg

Ffmpeg command to add shorter audio to video with loop

I am using this command to add audio to video, the audio is 18 seconds long and the video is 3 mins and 29 seconds long, this command adds audio but only for the first 18 seconds and then it stops

```
"-y","-stream_loop","-1","-i", audio,"-i",j, "-filter_complex",
                        "[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.5[a1];" +
                        "[1:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.8[a2];" +
                        " [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]",
                        "-map","1:v","-map","[out]","-c:v","copy","-c:a","aac","-shortest","-preset", "ultrafast", out
```

how can we add the audio in a loop and add it to the video

**Edit**

For the time issue I had made the following changes

```
"-y","-i",video,"-filter_complex","amovie="+audio+":loop=999,asetpts=N/SR/TB,aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.5[a1];" +[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.8[a2];" +"[a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]",
"-t", timetoedit,
"-map","0:v","-map","[out]","-c:v","copy","-c:a","aac","-shortest","-preset", "ultrafast", out
```

this works good if we want to add audio the whole video

now when we try to add audio which starts at a specific time and for a specific duration it fails 
here are two thing here, 
1) create a new clip with audio and video for specific duration
this command doesnot work

```
"-y","-i",video,,"ss",starttime,"-t", timetoedit,"-filter_complex","amovie="+audio+":loop=999,asetpts=N/SR/TB,aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.5[a1];" +[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.8[a2];" +"[a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]",
"-ss", starttime,"-t", timetoedit,
"-map","0:v","-map","[out]","-c:v","copy","-c:a","aac","-shortest","-preset", "ultrafast", out
```

or if we want to add just audio at a specific time

like

```
"-y","-i",video,"-filter_complex","amovie="+audio+":loop=999,asetpts=N/SR/TB,aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.5[a1];" +[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.8[a2];" +"[a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]",
    "-ss", starttime,"-t", timetoedit,
    "-map","0:v","-map","[out]","-c:v","copy","-c:a","aac","-shortest","-preset", "ultrafast", out
```

how can this be done

this is useful 
https://superuser.com/questions/708125/add-audio-at-specific-time-in-video-using-ffmpeg

but how can we use this for a specific start time and duration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
"-y","-i",j, "-filter_complex",
                        "amovie=audio:loop=999,asetpts=N/SR/TB,aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.5[a1];" +
                        "[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.8[a2];" +
                        " [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]",
                        "-map","0:v","-map","[out]","-c:v","copy","-c:a","aac","-shortest","-preset", "ultrafast", out
```

`-stream_loop` is buggy. Use the movie filter instead, which has a loop option.

Comment: this did work, but the video is 3min 29 sec long, it added audio only till 2 min 30 sec after that it was silent

Comment: it doesnt add audio to the last 45  seconds, dont know what is the issue

Comment: i have used -t 100 like commands for loop when creating video of image files , how can we use similar command to get exact duration for both audio and video

Comment: "-filter_complex","amovie="+audio+":loop=999,asetpts=N/SR/TB,aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.5[a1];" +
                                "[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.8[a2];" +
                                " [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]","-t", videotime,
                        "-map","0:v","-map","[out]","-c:v","copy","-c:a","aac","-shortest","-preset", "ultrafast", out :::::

Comment: I added the video time at end , 
      may be helpful for others, few more tests though will confirm later , thanks for your help Mulvya

Answer (score -2):

use code

```
./ffmpeg -i long.mp3 -filter_complex "amovie=background_music.mp3:loop=999[s];[0][s]amix=duration=shortest" test.mp3
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, you should add an explanation as to _why_ the asker should use this code and what exactly it achieves.